# Devexpress mvc html editor save to database

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am trying to get the content html of HtmlEditor of DevExpress mvc

There is not source code of the module and no examples

after adding the HtmlEditor, this is added automatically

```
 @Html.DevExpress().HtmlEditor(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "HtmlEditor";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "HtmlEditorPartialView" };        
        settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);

    }).GetHtml()
```

What is the right way to get the content of the editor, so that I can save it to database ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your can acces to the html code in the controller with

```
var content = HtmlEditorExtension.GetHtml("HtmlEditName");
```